# find method is not working in my react application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
function ProductScreen(props) {
  console.log(props.match.params.id);
  const product = data.products.find((x) => x.id === props.match.params.id);
 console.log(product);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{product}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the console of the product, it says undefined.

Comment: `product` is an object and it can't be rendered, if you need to render some specific property of a matching object, pass that : `<h1>{product.someProperty}</h1>`

Comment: What does data.products print?

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: What does `props.match.params.id` look like?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my React App. When I deployed it to Host server as "... `pageData.find((x) => x.id === parseInt(id));`" it returned `undefined`, but it worked fine in local server. I doubt it and changed to `==` and it worked fine. There might be a bug or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ProductScreen(props){
   console.log(props.match.params.id);
   const product = data.products.find( x => x._id === props.match.params.id);
   console.log(product);
   return <div>
      <h1>{product.name}</h1>
   </div>
 }
```

This is working fine you can give product.name or product.id..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are comparing the same data type between the data.products and props.match.params.id.

The datatype of props.match.params.id is a string. Hence, the data.products.id should be also a string.

Answer (score 0):

Because props.match.params.id is string and x.id is number that is why it is undefined you should convert props.match.params.id to number

```
 function ProductScreen(props) {
 const id = Number(props.match.params.id);
 const product = data.products.find((x) => x.id === id);

 return (
  <div>
   <h1>{product}</h1>
  </div>
   );
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `x._id.toString()===match.params.id`

Answer (score -2):

```js
const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id == props.match.params.id);
```

Use `==` instead of `===`

Comment: How do you tell? Just Try it. It works for me. And see whats happened.i just want to know that question asked member works for that?

Comment: What data are you testing with? Certainly not the same as OP since OP never presented his data, so it works for you because you use your own data that is designed to work in this particular scenario. The behavior of the regular equals operator (`==`) in JS is considered a design flaw and it's recommended to **always** use strict equals (`===`) instead. Your suggestion is contrary to JS *best practices*.